# What is the equivalent of db.UnprocessedDocuments in Lotus Notes Formula Language

Tags: lotus

I just want to get hold of the currently selected document from a view. I have to use formula language. Using Lotus Script I can easily access the document(s) e.g, this way:

Set dcSelectedDoc = db.UnprocessedDocuments

and then I can access the individual fields. I want to do the same but using formula language. I tried like this but no luck:   @GetField ( "CRMPath" ).

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Set the agent property "Target" = "All selected documents" and you can access the fields of the selected document, like `@Prompt([OK]; "CRMPath value"; CRMPath)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact I have created an action button which is a checkbox on a view. The purpose is to get/set/reset a flag in the selected document by coding in the click event of the button.

Comment: Create an agent that will process all selected documents. In the action button, call this angent by `@Command ([RunAgent];" agent name ")`. In the agent, you can read the value of the field simply by its name `MyFlag:= CRMPath`, you can set the new value using the `@SetField` formula... Sorry for my English, I use Google Translate.

Comment: As @IgorKudryashov advised, create a formula agent, that is being called from an action button and/or via actions menu, by default lotus formula agent works with all selected documents. The formula you have specified in the agent body will be called for every selected document. So, set the formula you want to apply for every document to the agent body. Please note, if you include Prompt calls inside of your formula, then Promp will be called for every selected document. I.e if you have selected 50 documents, you will get 50 prompt dialogs one after another.